# RavenDB and PredicateBuilder

Tags: lucene, ravendb, predicatebuilder

Is it possible to use the PredicateBuilder class to build a WHERE clause that RavenDB can interpret and use? I've tried session.Query() and LuceneQuery, but they each failed:

**Here is the session.Query() attempt:**

```
public static List<T> GetObjectList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = GetRavenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<T>().Where(whereClause).Take(int.MaxValue).ToList();
    }
}
```

**This is the *run-time* error:**

Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException: Cannot parse '( OR) OR': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.
Was expecting one of:
(List of expected items here).

**And if I try the LuceneQuery():**

```
public static List<T> GetObjectList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause)
{
    Func<T, bool> compiledWhereClause = whereClause.Compile();

    using (IDocumentSession session = GetRavenSession())
    {
        return session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>().Where(compiledWhereClause).Take(int.MaxValue).ToList();
    }
}
```

I get this **compile-time** error:

Error   2   'Raven.Client.IDocumentQueryBase>.Where(System.Func)' is obsolete: '
You cannot issue an in memory filter - such as Where(x=>x.Name == "Ayende") - on IDocumentQuery.

**Edit: This is what whereClause looks like in the first example:**

{f => ((False OrElse Invoke(x => (Convert(x).EquipmentId == value(ReadFromRaven.Logic.Readers.RavenReader`1+<>c__DisplayClassa[WriteToRaven.Data.Marker]).tempCoater.MarkerEquipmentId), f)) OrElse Invoke(x => (Convert(x).EquipmentId == value(ReadFromRaven.Logic.Readers.RavenReader`1+<>c__DisplayClassa[WriteToRaven.Data.Marker]).tempCoater.MarkerEquipmentId), f))}

**Edit 2: This is how I'm building the WHERE clause**

This is the call:

```
List<T> newList = RavenDataAccess.GetObjectList<T>(BuildWhereClause(x => x.MarkerReadTime > timeChunk.StartTime && x.MarkerReadTime <= timeChunk.EndTime));
```

And this is the BuildWhereClause() method signature and the parts of the method that matter:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildWhereClause(Expression<Func<T, bool>> readTimeExpression)

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> innerWhereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();

    foreach (Coater coater in coaters)
    {
        var tempCoater = coater;
        innerWhereClause = innerWhereClause.Or<T>(x => x.EquipmentId == tempCoater.MarkerEquipmentId);
    }

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> outerWhereClause = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
    outerWhereClause = outerWhereClause.And<T>(readTimeExpression);
    outerWhereClause = outerWhereClause.And<T>(innerWhereClause);

    _whereClause = innerWhereClause;

    return _whereClause;
```

Comment: In the 1st attempt, what does `session.Query<T>().Where(whereClause).Take(int.MaxValue).ToString()` show?

Comment: Also what does the Expression that is being passed into the GetListObject<T>(..) funciton look like in the debugger (`whereClause`)? Is there a chance that is has empty clauses, i.e. just contains "OR" statments and brackets?

Comment: @MattWarren ToString() shows this: ( OR) OR. I added the value of whereClause to my question. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the actual expression that you are trying to pass to the queries?

If you want to build a query dynamically, use Lucene Query, don't try to dynamically build something with linq.

Comment: I added the code for how I'm building the where clause. And I tried using a Lucene Query, but I got a compile time error. Are you saying I should use Lucene *without* PredicateBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

I  have same error. This is how I solve:

I use the predicateBulder from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx and called as follows:
Session.Query().Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();  Please note the I called predicate.Compile()methed.